# Analogue of "Get-Counter" in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

Powershell has the useful `Get-Counter` tool. In particular, I'm interested in:

```
(Get-Counter -Counter '\GPU Process Memory(*)\Total Committed').CounterSamples
```

I want to find a similar solution in C#, i.e. calculate GPU memory values for each running process. My searches on the Internet were unsuccessful, maybe I use infidels keywords for the search.

Right now I'm calling this method in C# workaround:

```
using (PowerShell PS_GPUProcessMemory = 
    PowerShell.Create().AddScript(@"(Get-Counter -Counter '\GPU Process Memory(*)\Total Committed').CounterSamples"))
    {
        //Do something
    }
```

However, how can I do without Powershell? How to use C# to find GPU memory values for each running process? thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.performancecounter?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: FWIW `Get-Counter` interfaces directly with the [PerformanceCounter API in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/pdh/)

Comment: Thanks. Trying to figure it out. How exactly to call ```\GPU Process Memory(*)\Total Committed```?

Comment: Judging by this issue in the situation with GPU, everything is not as simple as it seems. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389944/c-sharp-performance-counter-help-nvidia-gpu

Comment: To add to Mathias R. Jessen you could try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.getcounter.performancecountersampleset?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0