# Getting full name and usage of gpu using nvapi

Tags: c#, c++, c, nvapi

i am trying to get the full name of my gpu  and my gpu usage using nvapi.dll.
i have encounter this post on this website: [C# Performance Counter Help, Nvidia GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389944/c-sharp-performance-counter-help-nvidia-gpu).

he uses 2 sources, one in the dll itself  (for getting the usage) and for full name he uses the header file of  nvapi downloaded from the nevidia website.

There is any way i can avoid this duplication in my project?
using only the dll or using only the header files brought by nevidia.
Thanks for all the helpers

Comment: Do you need a solution in all 3 languages?

Comment: no, but it can be written in any language.

Answer (score 1):

you can load DLL file dynamically when you need it,

in c# you can use .Net Reflection (if dll is developed in .Net framework), for example :

```
var DLL = Assembly.LoadFile(@"path\to\your.dll");

Type t = DLL.GetType("myAssembly.ClassName");
CustomType result = t.InvokeMember("methodName", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, t, new object[] { @"method argument" });
```

if mentioned dll is not developed under .Net framework  but you are forced to use .Net framework (for more information see [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27298/Dynamic-Invoke-C-DLL-function-in-C))  :

```
int hModule = LoadLibrary(@"path\to\your.dll");
if (hModule == 0) return false;
IntPtr intPtr = GetProcAddress(hModule, "yourmethod_PTR");
```

if you want to use in c/c++ you can use following code  :

```
HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary("path\\to\\your.dll");

if (hGetProcIDDLL == NULL) {
   std::cout << "dll not found" << std::endl;
} 

int a = function_to_call("arguments");
```

NOTE: if you want to load dll from unknown source I recommend to use c/c++, because in c/c++ you can manage your memory easier and free all your resources after dll loading,

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  this isnt what i asked.

Comment: I got 2 sources that are basically  the same. I don't want to use both, if  i dont have to. But again thank you for your effort

Comment: clearly if you want use any of them easily load from dll path and use it,

Comment: yeah i know, but my question is how do i get the gpu name from nvapi.dll or get the usage from nvapi.h  (nevidia website). They act diffrently (in nvapi.dll  you query every function using some id) not like in nvapi.h

Comment: have you check http://eliang.blogspot.com/2011/05/getting-nvidia-gpu-usage-in-c.html sample code? mentioned link use both load library and print gpu usage.

Comment: yes, that is one of the sources i was talking about. He query using nvapi_queryinterface. I cant find any refrence to it any where. or the id for the function i am looking for (NvAPI_GetFullNAme) for quering it.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/15709958/1513086 link, I think the question sample code is exactly what you want,

Answer (score 0):

I  have found the list of functions id in https://github.com/processhacker/plugins-extra/blob/master/NvGpuPlugin/nvidia.c

In addition to
http://eliang.blogspot.com/2011/05/getting-nvidia-gpu-usage-in-c.html

i declared
`typedef int(*nvAPI_GPU_getFullName_t)(int *handle , char* name); nvAPI_GPU_getFullName_t  nvAPI_GPU_getFullName=NULL; nvAPI_GPU_getFullName=(nvAPI_GPU_getFullName_t)(*NvAPI_QueryInterface)(0xCEEE8e9FUL);`